# JSON-B REST payload validation

Tags: java, rest, validation, jsonb-api

I've developed a Java REST service using JSON-B to map the incoming payload to a POJO.

Now what I'd like to do is to validate the incoming payload, possibly against a JSON schema, but I haven't been able to find anything in this sense so far...

Is it possible to override the default JSON-B mapping process, hence catching any mapping exception and handling it on my own?

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this you could register your own JAX-RS provider that does the JSON (de)serialization and handle any errors there.

For example:

```
@Consumes({ "*/*" })
@Provider
public class JsonBProvider implements MessageBodyReader<Object> {

    private static final Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, 
                              Annotation[] annotations, 
                              MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object readFrom(Class<Object> clazz, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations,
                           MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, 
                           InputStream entityStream) 
                  throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        try {
            return this.jsonb.fromJson(entityStream, clazz);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Do your custom handling here
        }
    }
}
```

This will override the deserialization that occurs through JAX-RS and JSON-B.

NOTE: If you want to do the same thing for serialization as well, you can implement `MessageBodyWriter<Object>` in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Validation and deserialization are separate concerns, so I would tie them together only if I really need to, e.g. if you really must use JSON Schemas. But if you are free to choose your own way to declare the constraints, I recommend bean validation, e.g. a JAX-RS resource like this (note the `@Valid` annotation):

```java
@Path("ping")
public class PingBoundary {
    @POST
    public String ping(@NotNull @Valid Person addressee) {
        return "Hi " + addressee.getName() + "!";
    }
}
```

And a payload class like this (using the [lombok @Data annotation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data)):

```java
@Data
public class Person {
    private String name;
    @Min(0)
    private short age;
}
```

Passing an invalid `age` of -2 gives you a `400 Bad Request` with a helpful response body:

```
{
    "classViolations": [],
    "exception": null,
    "fieldViolations": [],
    "parameterViolations": [
        {
            "constraintType": "PARAMETER",
            "message": "must be greater than or equal to 0",
            "path": "ping.addressee.age",
            "value": "-2"
        }
    ],
    "propertyViolations": [],
    "returnValueViolations": []
}
```

Note that you should pass `-parameters` to the compiler, or the `path` would be `ping.arg0.age`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really stick to JSON Schema, validating JSON document while deserializing it can be achieved by using [Justify](https://github.com/leadpony/justify). There is a [Binding](https://github.com/leadpony/justify-examples/tree/master/justify-examples-binding) example which shows how to use the JSON validator with JSON-B. I hope the example code may help you.

Full Disclosure: I am the author of the library.